# Cycle to order the tasks with their subtasks

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem, I would like to place a task and before placing the next one, place the corresponding subtasks.

```
tasks 1
Task 1.1
Tasks 1.2
Task 1.2.1
Task 1.3
tasks 2
```

For that I have a database with two fields: `id and parent_id (contains the id of the parent task)`

And it already creates the relationship in Laravel so that it returns the corresponding children and parents of each task.

What I need is to make a cycle, to place it in the following way. Filling the subtasks of each task first, before moving on to the next task.

This is the relationship between tasks

```
public function parent()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
  return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `children` relationship like this:

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id')->with('children');
}
```

You can do this when querying:

```
//Assuming the model name is "Task"
$tasks = Task::whereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();
```

Comment: The search is perfect, and how would I place it on the screen using vue?

Comment: @JoseLopez you take the same concept. Just iterate over a component with the same approach. I cannot write the exact code here in the comment but I think you get what I mean.